# Upgrade log4j2(2.17.1) in Grails project with Grails version 2.5.6

Tags: grails, groovy, log4j, log4j2

We are using Groovy on Grails with grails version 2.5.6. This grails version downloads logj(1.2.17) jars. I have added following dependency in BuildConfig.groovy file.

`compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.17.1'`

This downloads latest log4j2 jar but grails-2.5.6.zip contains log4j-1.2.17.jar too. So to make sure that this old jar should not be used, I deleted log4j folder like following

```
RUN yum install -y wget && yum install -y unzip && wget https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/download/v$GRAILS_VERSION/grails-$GRAILS_VERSION.zip && \
    unzip grails-$GRAILS_VERSION.zip && \
    rm -rf grails-$GRAILS_VERSION/lib/log4j
```

Will this solve a problem? or there will still be log4j version used somewhere?

Comment: You are addressing 2 separate things.  Changes to your `BuildConfig.groovy` will affect what dependencies end up in your application jar.  The `yum` command you are running wil result in deleting stuff from the Grails installation, which is a separate thing, and is probably going to break Grails, not your app.

Comment: So in case of log4j upgradation this will work right?